# Disabling bunch of Text Boxes dynamically using a single Check Box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

MainWindow.xaml

```
<CheckBox Content="Enable" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="190,40,0,0" Name="checkBox_Enable" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Unchecked="checkBox_Enable_Unchecked" Checked="checkBox_Enable_Checked" />
    <Label Content="Fullscreen:" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,63,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Padding="1" />
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,86,243,0" Name="textBox_Hotkey_Fullscreen" Width="33" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Custom field:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,110,0,136" Name="label5" Padding="1" />
    <TextBox Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,131,0,0" Name="textBox_Hotkey_Customfield" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="33" />
    <Label Content="Window-related:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,155,0,87" Name="label4" Padding="1" />
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,0,0,112" Name="textBox_Hotkey_Windowrelated" Width="33" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    private void checkBox_Enable_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox_Hotkey_Fullscreen.IsEnabled = false;
        textBox_Hotkey_Customfield.IsEnabled = false;
        textBox_Hotkey_Windowrelated.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    //There are no problems after purging this function. However, the controls couldn't be "re-enabled", what obviously makes my concept pointless.  
    private void checkBox_Enable_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        textBox_Hotkey_Fullscreen.IsEnabled = true; 
        textBox_Hotkey_Customfield.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox_Hotkey_Windowrelated.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Why does it throw the NullReferenceException just after launch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does it throw the NullReferenceException just after launch?

Because not all controls are loaded yet when the `CheckBox` fires the event.

---

I would suggest [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) the `CheckBox` to a bool and binding the other controls' `IsEnabled` to that (or bind [directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) to the `CheckBox`).

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest use Binding like (remove event handlers from xaml)

```
 IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkBox_Enable, Path=IsChecked}"
```

for every control you want to enable/disable with the checkbox.

Comment: Yes this should work. You don't need to handle events when you have data binding.